# How does the compiler choose an overload when an overload with optional parameters exists

Tags: c#, recursion, overriding, optional-parameters

I don't understand how the compiler decides which overload to call if one exists with optional parameters. On [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments) I find:

> If two candidates are judged to be equally good, preference goes to a
>   candidate that does not have optional parameters for which arguments
>   were omitted in the call. This is a consequence of a general
>   preference in overload resolution for candidates that have fewer
>   parameters.

Consider this base class and its derived class:

```
public class FooBase {
    public virtual void Foo() { }
}

public class NonRecursiveFoo : FooBase {
    public override void Foo() {
        Foo();
    }

    public void Foo(string fooBar = null) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Now which method will be executed by the call to `Foo()` in `NonRecursiveFoo.Foo()`?

I would expect it to be a recursive call to itself, but it isn't. It will actually call the overload with the optional parameter. I would think that most programmers would expect this call to be recursive.

And even if I inherit from `NonRecursiveFoo` and try to make a recursive call, it won't be recursive:

```
public class StillNotRecursiveFoo : NonRecursiveFoo {
    public override void Foo() {
        Foo();
    }
}
```

This call to `Foo()` will also call the overload in `NonRecursiveFoo` with the optional parameter.

If I just have a single class with two overloads like this, calling `Foo()` will call the overload without parameters, not the one with a default parameter. This is the behavior I'd expect (and what MSDN seems to say).

```
public class FooAlone {
    public void Foo() {
        Foo();
    }

    public void Foo(string fooBar = null) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I do not understand how this works. I even wonder what I'd have to do if in fact I *do* want to perform a recursive call.

I'd also like to know if it is bad design to make use of this behavior. Is it ok to have an overload with default parameters and call it from the overridden method without parameters?

Finally, this means you can hide a non-virtual method without using the new keyword and without any compiler warnings.

```
public class BarBase {
    public void Foo() { }
}

public class Bar : BarBase {
    public void Foo(string fooBar = null) { }
}
```

Comment: [This page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691336(v=vs.71).aspx) says: "For example, the set of candidates for a method invocation does not include methods marked override (Section 7.3), and methods in a base class are not candidates if any method in a derived class is applicable (Section 7.5.5.1)".

Comment: of course it is bad design to make use of this behavior. its one of the reasons why VB.NET is so hard to maintain. You will need to debug to find that the "wrong" overload is selected after a fellow developer changed a signature in good faith, as the compiler would not even warn.